# How would I add a hug reaction command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have no idea what I’m doing. I don’t code but my friend helped me out up to this part

```js
   const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    
    
    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('This Bot is online!');
        client.user.setActivity('Prefix +k')
    });
    
    client.on('message', msg=>{
        if(msg.content === "+k Hello"){
            msg.reply('Welcome!');
        }
     })
     client.on('message', msg=>{
        if(msg.content === "+k Credits"){
            msg.reply('Pokemon DB for Info, MrTechGuy for code help!');
        }
     })
     client.on('message', msg=>{
        if(msg.content === "+k Credits"){
            msg.reply('Pokemon DB for Info, MrTechGuy for code help!');
        }
     })
     client.on('message', msg=>{
        if(msg.content === "+k DAList"){
            msg.reply('1 - Butterfree <:V:750540886680666282> <:grass:750540661396340826>, 2 = Butterfree <:VMAX:750540886701637743> <:grass:750540661396340826>,');
        }
     })
    
    client.login('[REDACTED]');
```

Again, how would I add a hug command that targets the user, e.g. +k hug @user 1, my friend is out for the month and I do not know how to do it

response: @user 2 hugged @user 1 ! (gif here)

Comment: appologies for bad formatting, 1st time here

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you will need to create a folder named "hug" and with images which are "gif".

```
if(message.content.startsWith('+k hug')) {
        let user = msg.mentions.users.first(); // refers to the user you wish to mention
        if (!user) {
            let maxImageNumber1 = 7; // represents the number of images in the folder
            let hug = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxImageNumber1 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            let imageName1 = `${hug}.gif` // if the images you put are png/jpg just remove the ".gif" with either ".png" or ".jpg"
            let imagePath1 = `/hug/${imageName1}` // folder name

            let file1 = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath1);
            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed1.setImage(`attachment://${imageName1}`)
            embed1.setDescription(`**${msg.author.username}** hugged their clone`)
            embed1.setColor('RANDOM')
            msg.channel.send({ files: [file1], embed: embed1 });
        }

        if (user) {
            let maxImageNumber1 = 7; // represents the number of images in the folder
            let hug = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxImageNumber1 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            let imageName1 = `${hug}.gif` // if the images you put are png/jpg just remove the ".gif" with either ".png" or ".jpg"
            let imagePath1 = `/hug/${imageName1}` // folder name

            let file1 = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath1);
            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed1.setImage(`attachment://${imageName1}`)
            embed1.setDescription(`**${msg.author.username}** hugged **${user.username}**`)
            embed1.setColor('RANDOM')
            msg.channel.send({ files: [file1], embed: embed1 });
        }
    }
```

**Im assuming you are using discord.js v12**

**TIP:**
*I'd recommend you define your prefix with something like `const prefix = '+k';` and when you want to make a command do this: `if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'hug')){}`*

Comment: would the file be in the original bot folder? the one with package.js etc?

Comment: ah, i see! sorry for the kind of silly question, its 2:am lol